# Echo PHP code into javascript innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP function that adds **+1** every time it runs.

```
function count_likes(){
  $collect=file_get_contents('like_counter.txt')+1;
  $count=file_put_contents("like_counter.txt", $collect);
  echo $collect;
```

---

I have a javascript that should run the PHP function mentioned earlier.
That is when the user clicks on the button every time, I call for the PHP function inside the `innerHTML` as a string.Unfortunately id doesn't change anything in the document.

```
var like=document.getElementById("like__image");
addEventListener("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var likeBox=document.getElementById("like__box");
    likeBox.innerHTML="<?php count_likes()  ?>";
});
```

How can I call my PHP function inside my Javascript ?

Comment: Your javascript has to send a ajax call to your PHP script. PHP is executed on the server, once the page has loaded is isn't available.

Comment: You're mixing Javascript with PHP and expect it to work together without hassle. You need to use ajax so a new request is made from javascript to your server, so PHP can execute that function.

Comment: @chris85 any other way to do this ?

Comment: No, but ajax is pretty easy with jquery. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: @Arie why doesn't the string get written, when we are using innerHTML  can javascript engine detect the PHP code and stop it from executing ?

Comment: Right now the PHP function gets called, always, when loading the page. That's how PHP works, it's only being executed when the page is executed/parsed. The click event doesn't do anything. You need to make an ajax call in the click event, to another file/page which only executes that function. That way the php gets executed when someone clicks. jQuery is a good lib to use as mentioned before.

Comment: @CoDINGinDARK: what happens with your code is that because PHP is executed on the server side when the page is requested, it will evaluate the `<?php count_likes()  ?>` statement and put a 4 (let's assume your count is 4), which will result in the code in your page looking like likeBox.innerHTML="4", thus always placing the same number within the like box.

Answer (score 1):

As PHP is running on your server and JavaScript is running on the user's browser you can't call that function directly.
But you can use AJAX to send a call to the server via JavaScript.

If you are using jQuery it will look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'www.yoursite.com/path/to/your/php/function',
    data: {action: 'your-action'},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(serverReturn) {
         // handle the PHP-return here
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm typing this on my mobile and it lost the example the first time. Thus the edit :)

Answer (score 1):

`Javascript` runs on the client side, while `PHP` runs on the server side, so your `echo` call will be rendered as-is, as there's no PHP interpreter on the browser side.

What you can do is to add a `count_likes.php` script that calls your function, and have an ajax call from the client side that will set the `innerHTML` of the desired element.

So instead of

```
likeBox.innerHTML="<?php count_likes()  ?>";
```

you could do

```
$("#like__box").load("count_likes.php");
```

assuming you have jquery included in your site. Think of the `load` call as an asynchronous version of the original setting of `innerHTML`.

Comment: That's an interesting way to get really shorten expression, and so it looks pretty suitable to keep the "spirit" of what the question was about. BTW, I'm using jQuery for times and didn't even noticed that method exists! Thanks.